# how can i style one cell of QTableWidget without any effect on the other cells?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

i am working on a table and i use QTableWidget in my project

and i need to change the color or the style of one cell only or one row only , i do not want to style all of cells.

[image]

in the above image i changed all of cells but i want to change one cell or one row only.

is there any chance or way to do it ?

Comment: Don't use stylesheets for that. Just double click the table, go to the "Items" tab, select the cell, press the "Properties" button and set the background. Also remove any `::item` selector in the stylesheet for that table.

Comment: yes i understand you but i want to do it by the code for example the user will enter number 1 and the program will add a new row and the new row will be normal except the second cell , it will be balck for example

Answer (score 1):

I would implement my own [QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and set the table to use that ([setItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) and friends).

It can be very simple for your needs, probably, just need to re-implement one method, `QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption()` and inside that set the [backgroundBrush](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#backgroundBrush-var) property of the `QStyleOptionViewItem` to whatever you need.

Here's a C++ example (sorry):

```cpp
class BackgroundColorDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    public:
        using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;

    protected:
        void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *o, const QModelIndex &idx) const override
        {
            // first call the base class method
            QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(o, idx);
            // Now you can override the background color based on some criteria,
            // in the data for example, or the Delegate could have a custom
            // property which the View sets as needed.
            if (idx.data(Qt::UserRole).toString() == "color-me-blue")
                o->backgroundBrush = QBrush(Qt::blue);
        }
};
```

**ADDED**:
Found a Py example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63119266/3246449), so the delegate would look something like this (untested):

```py
class BackgroundColorDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toString() == "color-me-blue"):
            option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue);

class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setItemDelegate(BackgroundColorDelegate(self))
```

**ALSO**:
Another approach is to set the relevant model item's `Qt.BackgroundRole` to the desired color. This would work with any view delegate (including the default ones). Depending on how you're building your model, and especially if you're already using a custom model, this may be the better approach.

So for example if you want to set the background color while you're *building* the model, you could

`model.setData(index, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, QtGui.QBrush(Qt.blue))`

Or if using a `QStandardItem` there is [a method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstandarditem.html#setBackground) for that:

`item.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue))`

Or if you implement your own model then you could return the correct color from the [QAbstractItemModel::data()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) method, something like

```py
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toString() == "color-me-blue":
                return QtCore.Qt.blue
            else:
                return QtCore.Qt.transparent
        return super().data(index, role)
```

HTH,
-Max